# How to ask for a raise after passing probation

Tags: salary, negotiation, probation

I have interviewed at a company and asked for a salary of 25k. They have given me an offer of 24k and they said they will consider again after I have passed the probation. I passed the probation 1 and a half months ago already and they still have not mentioned anything. should I take it as that my skill is not sufficient enough for a salary of 25k or should I ask for the raise. If I should ask, how can I make it seems like I am not a money hungry person.

Answer (score 9):

If you agreed on a reevaluation after the end of your probation this reevalution should take place. And it should be explicit.
If it is implicit it didn't happen.

So yes, go and ask for it. Usually there should be a probation end talk/meeting anyway.
Maybe someone just forgot.

You still have your job, which should be taken as a good sign.

Don't worry about being conceived as "money hungry". We all are working for money.
Not exclusively, but money matters. Anybody telling you something different is lying or naive.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure I would invite the person for a meeting (the one who said they'd consider after your probation) and approach the subject with them again.

Don't be forceful when asking and try to remember to be professional about it. I'm hoping they have it in writing that this consideration could be made.  If not, it's known as a 'gentleman's agreement'.

This is something which they should acknowledge and give you some form of answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to be ashamed of. Just be genuine and communicate your needs in a friendly but
urgent way.

Depending on the feedback you got about your work - may it be explicit in paper form or implicit by means of commendation - you may put a bigger focus on the good work you did, and not only on the earlier agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Many companies will pay as little as possible at every opportunity.  They are probably hoping you never bring it up.
Always remain respectful and positive, even if they won't give you a raise.  Sometimes you have to be patient, but communication is the key, and if possible, documentation in writing of what you are promised, is always important to have.
You should do some research as to what your position typically pays in your region and ask your supervisor / director, what would you need to do to be worth this much to your company?  If there is a quantifiable output (eg X websites per month ) that is always better so that you have a concrete goal.
Practice what you want to say before-hand.  Remember to breathe and don't be nervous, if you project fear they may sense weakness and pay you less than you're worth.